# Visual Studio 2015 & Resharper 2016.2

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have an issue after reinstalling pc. In the past I remember Ctrl + Shift + Space hot key if cursor in the method was showing method signature and with arrows Up/Down I could walk through all overloads for that method. Now I have no idea how to see all method overloads except object browser.

One more issue Ctrl + [Alt] + Left Click if the method was in external assembly was opening it on object browser. Now this is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose in the [ReSharper options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Options__Environment__IntelliSense__Parameter_Info.html) how to switch between overloads - see ReSharper → Options → IntelliSense → Parameter Info. You can choose between the up/down cursor keys or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

And you can choose how navigation to external code is handled in ReSharper → Options → Tools → External Sources. The radio buttons at the top allow choosing between default VS navigation, navigating to the Object Browser, to ReSharper's Assembly Explorer or (my favourite) navigating to the source, either by downloading it from a source server, or decompiling it on the fly. See the [help page for more details](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Options__Tools__External_Sources.html).